# Need help trying to identify the source of a 404 error for a Java web app

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm not a Java developer but I need to determine why our app suddenly gives a 404 error in only one of our environments even though the code is the same in all.

When I try to navigate to the main home page URL, the code in the following controller is executed.

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
```

Immediately, it checks an attribute on the incoming HTTP request and it returns a 404 error.

httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code")

I'm trying to use Chrome tools to see what the missing resource is. Besides some 404 errors for some missing jquery png files I only see a couple of messages  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" messages that both point to the first line of the default page index fil. This file used to have the following lines:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><!-- Solution for Cacheable SSL Page Found Vulnarability -->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"><!-- Solution for Cacheable SSL Page Found Vulnarability -->
```

but I blanked these lines out, cleared the cache and the 404 still pointed to the now blank 1st line of the index file.

I also tried to put a break in the ErrorController and looked at the Java stack to see of I can try to determine what threw the error but I was looking at a very deep stack of system code that no noob mortal should have to look at.

I get this error running locally and on a web server. If I run locally and point to another database, I do not get the error, so this suggests that it is data related. I tried to look for any ajax call to the database and check for a failed or suspicious response but so far, I am not finding any.

I've never written a line of Java code, but I have experience with .NET.

**Any suggestions on how to determine what is throwing the 404 error?**

Comment: It should not be `value = "/errors"`? With `/`?

Comment: Thanks. I did change it to @RequestMapping(value = "/errors", method = RequestMethod.GET) and it still returned the same error.

Comment: Maybe your returned `ModelAndView` is missing or in not right location? Are you also sure all resources path from the returned view, is right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all my resource links are valid. thanks.